# Remove background image and prevent it from flashing on page load

Tags: css, background-image

I have the following html markup :

```
<div class="header site-header">

</div>
```

and the following css:

```
.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  background-image: url(../content/logo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 90px;
}

.site-header {
   background-color: #fff;
   display: block;
   margin-top: 0;
   position: relative;
}
```

I use the following css to remove the background image but on page refresh i can still see the orginal image briefly flash before it disappears:

```
.header {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat: unset;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0077b4;
}
```

How do this prevent this brief flash of the image when the page is refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

It works well for me. Where did you place the styles?

```css
.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  background-image: url(https://saportakinsta.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Scene-Portrait-of-a-Lady.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 90px;
}

.site-header {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat: unset;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0077b4;
}
```

```html
<div class="header site-header">

</div>
```

Comment: If your site does not work, then you need to look at your site.